Legal to use free google drive account for commercial use?
I am not sure, does the new terms of service allow the usage of a free google drive account for say, a small business. If so, are there any restrictions to this? Btw: here is a link to the updated google tos.
https://www.google.com/drive/terms-of-service/

What "new terms of service"? The page you linked to is 4 years old.

That is the current terms of service, as opposed to the one used in 2018

Did you read the terms of service you linked to?  Did you have a specific question about them, or are you expecting others to read them for you?

I am not a lawyer, so I wanted to double check there was no prohibition on commercial use, especially since there was a change between the previous version.

Sorry, but interpreting a contract for you is giving legal advice. Work it out for yourself or hire a lawyer.

It's pretty plain language. It would be pretty obvious if it had any provisions that distinguished free versus paid accounts, and personal versus commercial use.

I believe there is no prohibition against such commercial use indicated in the TOS. Google makes it clear it gives you the right to “ upload, submit, store, send and receive content” in drive, and does not state that files which could potentially be helpful to commercial activities would be an exception.
